# Ordenar html com grid angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, grid

estou precisando de uma dica de como ordenar elementos na minha home sem que apareçam espaços em branco.
O problema é: Tenho uma página que lista todos os serviços cadastrados, está página está com paginação que lista os elementos 8 por página, até aqui tudo ok, lista perfeitamente os elementos, a questão é que aparecem espaços em branco que não são desejados, eles ocupam espaços que poderiam ser ocupados por elementos listados.

```html
<h3 ng-if="services.length == 0">Nenhum serviço encontrado.</h3>
     <div class="col-4 col-no-left" ng-repeat="service in services">
      <a class="service-card"  href="{{ service.url }}">
       <p class="title " >{{service.name}}</p>
       <p ng-bind-html="service.description | limitTo:150 "><p>{{service.description.length >= 15  ? "..." : " "}}</p><p class="btn">ver mais</p></p>
       <span ng-repeat="category in service.categories">{{ category.name }}.</span>
      </a>
     </div>
```

Este bloco é que faço a organização dos elementos na views. Procurei algumas soluções, vi sobre a masonry e sobre o UI-grid, mas não encontrei um passo a passo de como instalar e configurar os mesmos. 
Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz aqui um exemplo usando o [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/).

Você só precisa incluir seus dados na propriedade `data` do atributo `ui-grid` no seu HTML.

O resultado é o seguinte:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appExemploTabela', ['ui.grid']);

  angular
    .module('appExemploTabela')
    .controller('TabelaController', TabelaController);

  TabelaController.$inject = [];

  function TabelaController() {
    var tabela = this;
    
    iniciar();
    
    function iniciar() {
      tabela.registros = [];
      tabela.registros.push({id: 1, nome: 'Registro 1'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 2, nome: 'Registro 2'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 3, nome: 'Registro 3'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 4, nome: 'Registro 4'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 5, nome: 'Registro 5'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 6, nome: 'Registro 6'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 7, nome: 'Registro 7'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 8, nome: 'Registro 8'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 9, nome: 'Registro 9'});
      tabela.registros.push({id: 10, nome: 'Registro 10'});
    }
  }
})()
```

```css
.minha-tabela {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="styleSheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.2.9/ui-grid.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.2.9/ui-grid.js"></script>

<div ng-app="appExemploTabela">
  <div ng-controller="TabelaController as tabela">
    <div ui-grid="{data: tabela.registros}" class="minha-tabela"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```